# IE sends cyrillic url-parameters in wrong coding

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, url, encoding

I have to pass cyrillic symbols as url parameter. And it works perfectly in google chrome but damn IE does not do as good.

Here's my simple code, invoking a page and passing url-parameter:

```
location.assign("http://127.0.0.1/cs105/livelink/Open/myreport?param=Параметр")
```

I've started to debug backend piece and I've found out that when I do this request in chrome, I get parm value exactly in cyrrilic symbols, but when sent from IE I get this text in ISO-8859-1 encoding.

Normally I would encodeURI this string and decode it in backend, but in this case it's not an option.

Is there some IE configuration option that I'm missing or a special way to pass data as UTF-8 and not it ISO-8859-1?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any news about this issue?

Comment: yeah, as I remember it turned out that it wasn't a coding issue - server read encoded or non-encoded symbols perfectly well. The problem was with lenght of the parameter which exceeded the maximum url length.